# How does Kafka Consumer behave when poll timeout has expired?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can someone let me know how a consumer is expected to behave after the below log? Will the consumer be considered dead and a new instance will be spawned due to consumer group rebalancing? How is this behaviour with `RangeAssignor` and `CooperativeStickyAssginer`?

> consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records

For  example, let's say I have two instances of a consumer running on two different machines. Both instances of the consumer belong to the same consumer-group and consume from the same topic with 10 partitions. In this case, what is expected when I see the above logs in both the consumers for RangeAssignor and CooperativeStickyAssginer?

Right now sometime I am observing that after the above log is printed on both the consumer instances then the machine on which the consumer instances are running stops consuming any new messages. My understanding was that after the above log is printed then the consumer instances will be removed from the group and new consumers will be started via the rebalancing. Is not my understanding correct? If yes then what is not allowing this to happen? `session.timeout.ms` is default.

I am using Kafka Client 3.5.1 with Kafka Broker 2.8.1.

I posted a similar query in Kafka mailing list but did not get any reply. So posting it here also.